# Executing a bash command in a docker container from python script on host fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to execute a bash command from python script that is wrapped in a `docker exec` call as the command needs to be executed inside a container.

This script is being executing on the host machine:

```
command_line_string = f"java -cp {omnisci_utility_path}:{driver_path} com.mapd.utility.SQLImporter" \
        f" -u {omni_user} -p {omni_pass} -db {database_name} --port {omni_port}" \
        f" -t {self.table_name} -su {denodo_user} -sp {denodo_pass}" \
        f" -c {self.reader.connection_string}"\
        f" -ss \"{read_data_query}\""

# in prod we have docker so we wrap it in docker exec:
if(args.env_type == "prod"):
    command_line_string = f"docker exec -t {args.container_id} /bin/bash -c \"{command_line_string}\""
            
command_line_args = shlex.split(command_line)
command_line_process = subprocess.Popen(
    command_line_args,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
process_output, _ = command_line_process.communicate()
```

However, when I execute the command, supplying the arguments I get a "Java Usage" response suggesting that the java command I am invoking did not have the correct parameters:

```
2021-09-01:09:19:09 [default_omnisci_ingestion.py:64] INFO - docker exec -t 5d874bffcdf8 /bin/bash -c "java -cp /omnisci/bin/omnisci-utility-5.6.5.jar
:/root/denodo-8-vdp-jdbcdriver.jar com.mapd.utility.SQLImporter -u admin -p mypass -db omnisci --port 6274 -t MyTable -su sourceDBuser -sp sourceDBpass -c jdbc:vdb://sourceDBURL -ss "SELECT
  basin as Basin,
  reservoir as Reservoir,  cast(case when wkt like '%M%' Then wkt Else replace(wkt, 'POLYGON ', 'MULTIPOLYGON (') || ')' End as varchar(999999)) as wkt
FROM
  schema.myTable;""
2021-09-01:09:19:10 [command_executor.py:10] INFO - Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
2021-09-01:09:19:10 [command_executor.py:10] INFO - (to execute a class)2021-09-01:09:19:10 [command_executor.py:10] INFO - or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
2021-09-01:09:19:10 [command_executor.py:10] INFO - (to execute a jar file)
...
```

I know that the problem is due to the use of quotes but I just don't understand how to go about them.
For example, the java command I am nesting inside `bin/bash -c` needs to be wrapped with quotes like sl
`bin/bash -c "java -cp ..."`

**Note**: the `command works fine if I execute it in our dev env where we do not have the "docker setup" and we execute the command as it is but on Stage we have the system running in a container thus the reason why I need to use` docker exec` to invoke the same command in the contaner

Comment: Heredoc? https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html